# Any ideas on how to implement a USB man in the middle circuit?

Tags: usb, multiplexer

I'm looking for an easy way to get in between of a HID USB communication.
Can it work by multiplexing a single usb port on an AVR?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to just monitor the bus, or are you looking to inject data too?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but it's definitely not that easy. USB is pretty timing sensitive, and I'm pretty sure that you can't relay an enumeration request between two USB ports without timing issues killing it off.

Depending on what you really are after, there are free usb sniffer tools you can use. sniffusb and usbsnoop come immediately to mind.

Comment: I see, thanks!
How about instead of sitting in the middle and talking to both sides, just tap into the communication passively (without the intent to change the data), logic analyzer style. Can it work?

Comment: This is definitely possible. The USBee DX claims to be able to do this, so I would imagine any logic analyzer could take a crack at it.

Comment: Can an AVR running on 12Khz oscillator function as a passive listener (slow usb, hid)?

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing a usb host to talk to the usb-device, and implement a usb-client to talk to the usb-host.

Then your mcu sits there in the middle and forwards the hight level commands, 
but keeps the low-level stuff locally (things like enumeration).

But it is not a easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

USB sniffing is hard. There are plenty of commercial tools to do it, or you can dump everything going through the PC end.

If you really want to look at the USB signals have a look at:

http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_6.htm

http://embeddeddsp.embedded.com/story/OEG20020321S0027

Answer (score 1):

[$400 solution](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb12/)

[Free (Linux) Solution](http://www.linux-usb.org/USBMon/dissertation/USB-dissertation.htm)

Comment: @Brad - Do you have any personal experience with the Beagle USB 12 Protocol Analyzer?